# How to create first post, fifth post full width, rest in three columns and so on

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress development, I am learning how to make a theme from scratch. I don't want to use any plugin to achieve this.

How to create first post/ fifth post/ ninth post full width, rest in three columns and so on.

I tried this but first post is not repeating

```html
<?php get_header() ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
  <?php if ($i++ == 0) : ?>
  <div class="col-sm-12 blog">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 p-0">
     <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
     <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
     <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <?php else: ?>
  <div class="col-sm-4 blog py-3">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
   <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
   <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endwhile ?>
 </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

[find my screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpPtw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text isn't very clear but i'm assuming you want to have 1 big post and 3 tiny posts pattern.

To achieve this you will need to tell your code that the first one or when the post number is divided by 4 and the remainder is 0, the post should be big.

Code:

```
<?php get_header() ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
        <?php if ($i == 0 || $i % 4 == 0) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 blog">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 p-0">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
                    <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 blog py-3">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
            <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
            <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++;endwhile ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: both the answers are correct, it says you can check only one :(

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
<?php get_header() ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
        <?php if ($i % 4 == 0) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 blog">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 p-0">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
                    <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 blog py-3">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
            <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
            <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php 
        $i++;
        endwhile ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```